# What is this plate/wheel/disc called?

Tags: control

So this plate would attach to a motor and an arm would be attached to any one of the holes. As the motor rotates the plate it causes the arm to move in a reciprocating fashion. In this example, changing the hole changed the length of travel of the arm in increments of 1/2".  Think aluminum can crusher.  My question is, what is the proper name for this so I can order one online.  I've spent hours with different word combinations but have not found one.  I've seen them in pictures and in person, so I know they exist.  What is it called
[image]

Comment: it could be a `crank`

Comment: I have made these plates for more than one project and it never occured to me it would have a name. And based on google search it seams it doesn't have a name in english, but if you look up "indexing dividing plate" you see something similar. Indexer is a tool used by machinists for gear cutting.

Comment: Still havent found this exactly, but your suggestion got me closer than I was before. Thanks Billy.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible names, depending on the application and motor type.

When used with RC servo motors, they can be called [*servo horns*](https://www.servocity.com/servo-horns). These motors usually have a unique spline shaft.

[image: Servo Horn]

When used with other motors with a rounded shaft, they can be called [*motor hubs*](https://www.robotshop.com/collections/hubs-couplers).

[image: Motor Hub]

Comment: These terms still didnt find the round plate I am looking for but the servo arm search yielded products that accomplish the intent of the disc.  I appreciate your help Mepix.  Im still trying to find the disc version though just out of principle and to prove to myself that I am not crazy!

Comment: Good luck finding the name of the part, I'm curious myself as well. If you do find it, don't forget to come back and post your own answer!